# SOAPFAULTEXCEPTION while trying to consume a webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, cxf

I have been experimenting a bit with web service when I stumbled on a situation. The relevant details are:

- I am using eclipse,cxf and tomcat.
- I created a simple web service which prints hello. It does not have any arguments in its method. When I call this web service from a client everything works fine.
- But, when I create a web service with arguments in the method, I am getting a weird exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException:
>   Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"----", local:"loginid").
>   Expected elements are
>   <{}tokenstring>,<{}devicetype>,<{}loginid>,<{}password>,<{}deviceid> 
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
>     at $Proxy29.getUserInformation(Unknown Source)  at
>   servicepackage.ServiceClassPortType_ServiceClassPort_Client.main(ServiceClassPortType_ServiceClassPort_Client.java:71)
>   Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Unmarshalling Error:
>   unexpected element (uri:"----", local:"loginid"). Expected elements
>   are
>   <{}tokenstring>,<{}devicetype>,<{}loginid>,<{}password>,<{}deviceid> 
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
>     ... 2 more

Can someone tell me what is happening and what should I do to solve this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT seems that you have changed the order of XML tags in WSDL
loginid was third one, but now the server expects it at first.

Regenerate the web service client, and try.